# Comparação de if-else não continuando mesmo com else em Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho duas variáveis:

```
int trabalhadorFormal;
int dispensadoIndireta;
```

E com elas estou usando `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` para confirmar como uma espécie de boolean, sim ou não, para o usuário.

```
trabalhadorFormal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
    "É trabalhador formal?",
    "Por favor selecione",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

dispensadoIndireta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
    "Foi dispensado indiretamente?",
    "Por favor selecione",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

E com isto tenho o seguinte código:

```
 if (trabalhadorFormal == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
     if (dispensadoIndireta == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
         do {
             opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("[1] - É empregado doméstico" + 
                 "\n[2] - Não é empregado doméstico"));

             switch (opcao) {
                 case 1:
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "É empregado doméstico!");
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não é empregado doméstico!");
                     break;
                 default:
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção inválida!");
                     break;
             }
         } while (opcao != 1 && opcao != 2);           
     } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Teste!");
     }
 }
```

O único problema é que quando eu seleciono as opções que irão me levar para o `else` após o segundo `if`, nada ocorre e o programa fecha me retornando com sucesso, como simplesmente ignorando o `else`.

O que está ocorrendo de errado aqui? Na construção do `if-else`?

Comment: O que o debugger diz sobre o valor de `dispensadoIndireta`?

Comment: Repliquei aqui seu código e funcionou certinho, segundo seu código se você optar por não ele entra no seu do while, e no do while se você indicar uma condição válida ele dá um break e sai do laço. No segundo if se você dá um sim ele vai para o else e imprime teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você entra com a opção não para dispensaIndireta no segundo if ele sai da condição do else, então o else não será processado, olha esse exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean condicao = true;
        int opcao = 2;

        if (condicao == true) {
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Opcao 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Opcao 2");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Opcao 3");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Para condicao false entra aqui!");
        }
    }
```

No caso acima imprime Opcao 2 e não faz mais nada, pois defini ***true*** para **condicao** e o *if* recebe ***true*** então o *else* não será mais chamado, ou seja, a condição já foi executada.